# Do culture points 'roll over' if you opt out of adopting a new policy?

Tags: civilization-5

When asked to adopt a social policy, you can right click to opt out.
If you do this, do you lose those cultural points, or do they roll over until your next cultural advancement?

I don't like any of the currently available social policies, but I have been asked to choose a new policy twice.

Comment: Notice that after the December 2010 patch, this question is only valid if the "allow policy saving" option is selected when creating a new game - otherwise social policy adoption cannot be skipped for later turns.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will accumulate Culture Points even if you already have enough points to buy a policy.  This can be very important strategically:

- If you build the **Cristo Redentor** Wonder (or are close to building it) you should wait to buy your policy until after it's complete, in order to gain the 33% discount.
- If you build or annex more cities the cost of future policies goes up, so you should purchase your next policy before obtaining a new city.

As far as not wanting any of the currently available policies, sometimes you have to just take a non-ideal policy to open up future policies you DO care about.

Comment: You can even do a cultural win by saving up tons of culture points then giving away all your cities (except the capital) to an AI player.  Drastically reduces the culture cost per policy but leaves you with tons of culture points.

Comment: Wow, that is quite an amusing exploit :)

Comment: That is a good one, nice job figuring that out.

Comment: This particular exploit is no longer possible as of the 12/15/10 patch.  The cost for policies will never go down.

Answer (score 6):

The culture points are still accumulating, you can spend them at any time you want. Just be careful, if you build a new city in the meantime the cost for the policies goes up.

Answer (score 2):

Culture Points will continue to accumulate even on turns you select a social policy.

As of the 12/15 patch, it is impossible to delay picking a social policy.